# How to join groupby subquery with admin queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to do a group by on a pre-aggregated dataset, and join that data with the ModelAdmin. So for various entities I would like to show aggregated data similar to google analytics.

I have a model for the entity

```
class Link(AnalyticalObject):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

and a model for the aggregated data

```
class LinkByDayAnalytic(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    day = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    clicks = models.IntegerField()
    emails = models.IntegerField()
    purchases = models.IntegerField()
    revenue = models.FloatField()
```

and I am trying to modify the queryset on the modeladmin to do a groupby and join the data with the items (links in this case).

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    '''
        Do analytics query
    '''
    qs.annotate(newcol=RawSQL("select lander_id, SUM(purchases) as purchases FROM manager_campaignbydayanalytic GROUP BY lander_id",[]))
    print qs.query
    #qs.

    return qs
```

I have attached this screenshot to illustrate my desired outcome. I can't seem to wrap my head around annotate, attach and extra.

[Desired admin outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf1EO.png)

Comment: What is `lander_id` and `manager_campaignbydayanalytic` in your subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way in django to do custom group by.

But fortunately, for that desired result, you won't need any custom one.

First, define `related_name` on `link` field in your `LinkByDayAnalytic` model:

```
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name="by_day_analytics")
```

Now prepare your query:

```
    qs.annotate(
        purchases_analytic=Sum('by_day_analytics__purchases"),
        clicks=Sum('by_day_analytics__clicks'),
        emails=Sum('by_day_analytics__emails'),
        email_pct=Sum('by_day_analytics__emails') / Sum('by_day_analytics__clicks') * 100,
        # etc...
    )
```

And next - use that calculated values in custom columns (they won't appear in list display automatically).